# Martini session not moving between requests

Tags: go, martini

I am writing a web app using the martini-contrib session library. I seem to have run into an issue though. My session don't seem to be moving between requests in the browser.

I have followed the exact guidelines that were outline in the example code, yet my code does not work. Below is the pertinent parts:

Login page:

```
 m.Get("/login", binding.Bind(LoginForm{}), func(r render.Render, session sessions.Session, form LoginForm) string {
    // Get info from the database.
    conn, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "ocdns.db")
    defer conn.Close()

    // Prepare the statement.
    stmt, err := conn.Prepare(`
      SELECT user_id, username, name_first, name_last, role, team_id
      FROM User
      WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
      LIMIT 1;
    `)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    // Query the database and set appropriate items if a row was actually returned.
    var id string
    var username string
    var name_first string
    var name_last string
    var role string
    var team_id string

    err = stmt.QueryRow(form.Username, form.Password).Scan(&id, &username, &name_first, &name_last, &role, &team_id)

    if err != nil {
      log.Print("!! Bad login from " + form.Username + " with " + form.Password)
      log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
      log.Print(">" + id + "<")
      log.Print(">" + username + "<")
      log.Print(">" + name_first + "<")
      log.Print(">" + name_last + "<")
      log.Print(">" + role + "<")
      log.Print(">" + team_id + "<")
      session.Set("id", id)
      session.Set("username", username)
      session.Set("name_first", name_first)
      session.Set("name_last", name_last)
      session.Set("role", role)
      session.Set("team_id", team_id)

      v := session.Get("name_first")
      if v == nil {
        log.Print("!! Uh oh.")
      }
      log.Print(v.(string))

      return "OK"
    }

    return "Bad"
  })
```

Session check page:

```
  m.Get("/session", func(session sessions.Session) string {
    var c Context

    i := session.Get("id")
    if i == nil {
      c.Id = -1
    }

    c.Id, _ = strconv.Atoi(i.(string))


    i = session.Get("username")
    if i == nil {
      log.Print("!! username")
    }

    if vs, ok := i.(string); ok {
      c.Username = vs
    } else {
      log.Print(vs)
    }

    log.Print(c)

    j, _ := json.Marshal(c)

    return string(j)
  })
```

Context struct:

```
type Context struct {
  Id          int       `json:"id"`
  Username    string    `json:"username"`
  NameFirst   string    `json:"name_first"`
  NameLast    string    `json:"name_last"`
  Role        string    `json:"role"`
  TeamId      int       `json:"team_id"`
}
```

Finally, my session declaration:

```
// Create session store.
store := sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret123"))
m.Use(sessions.Sessions("my_session", store))
```

I have tried emptying my cache to get it to work, but it won't. I did look in Chrome's developer tools to see if storage was being used and I did find that the session moved between two pages, but the output of the `session` request was an empty `Context` json stucture.

What I need is to figure out why my session data seems to be getting lost between requests and what I can do to fix it. I have looked on here and while nothing fits my exact problem, I did find that there were ones that had problems with their web server configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your first function call as follow to make sure it must goto session first before login.

```
m.Get("/login", SOME_FUNC_TO_SEESION, func(r render.Render, session sessions.Session, form LoginForm) string {
```

Here is sample video, hope it help you. Your code should work well.
https://gophercasts.io/lessons/8-auth-part-2